# mocking the configuration constant for unit tests in Angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a constant that handles the configuration of several environnements in Angular.This is the implementation of this constant:

```
 angular.module('config', [])
   .constant('configuration', {
   env: '@@env',
   apiEndpoint: '@@apiEndpoint',
   authorization: '@@authorization'
  });
```

I want to test that a URL is well retrieved so I implemented this code in my test script:

```
it('should fetch the summary', inject(function ($injector) {
       // Given
            $httpBackend.expectGET($injector.get("configuration").apiEndpoint +'/mccafeordersummary')
  .respond({ foo: 'bar' });

// When
  mcCafeService.find().success(function(summary) {
    // Then
     expect(summary).toEqual({ foo: 'bar' });
     done();
   });
  $httpBackend.flush();
  }));
```

I know that I should mock this constant at the begining but in all the examples I have seen in the internet they change the value of the constant.What I want is to retrieve the constant with its own value.Please help me if you have any suggestions.